# XSD with HTML tags along with custom xml

Tags: xml, xsd-validation, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am planning to create a custom XML format and have a validation for it using an XSD. Hence I want to create an XSD that can validate my custom XML, which contains custom elements can contain any valid HTML tag and the HTML tags can contain my custom elements.

A sample of my custom xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root-custom-element type='card/text'>
    <p style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 20.0px Avenir; color:            #010101">
    <span style="font-family: 'Avenir-Roman'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 20.00pt">Hello

    Some text

    </span>
    </p>
    <resource-element type="image/jpeg" resource-id="lh6rdbf14a0e023724d918086d0b8d77152e7"></resource-element>
    <p>
    <span>
    test text
    </span>
    <span>
    fkgfiughs
    </span>
    </p>

    <p>
    <resource-element type="audio/x-aac" resource-id="lh6rdcf34bf0fc03849348a1875fe2e8d1192"></resource-element>
    </p>
    </root-custom-element>
```

The test schema i have created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="custom-html.xsd"
        namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />

    <xs:element name="root-custom-element" type="rootCustomElement" />

    <xs:element name="resource-element" type="resourceElement" />

    <xs:complexType name="resourceElement">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="resource-id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="rootCustomElement">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="resource-element" />
                <xs:any namespace="xhtml:http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" processContents="strict" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="bgcolor" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But when i try to validate the xml against the schema i get the error

```
Exception: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'p'. One of '{resource-element, WC["http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"]}' is expected.
```

The custom-html.xsd schema is the modified version of xhtml-strict.xsd containing only the html tags i require. And 'p' is among one of them.